# sqlalchemy Sqlite not loading table rows

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlite with sqlalchemy:

when I execute this command:

```
engine.execute("select * from teams");
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x245b190>
```

Thus, it works as it returns a reference

I've a .py file which contain the class Team:

```
class Team(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'teams'
        id = Column(Integer,autoincrement=False, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(255))
        flag = Column(String(255))
        url = Column(String(255))
```

I import Team `from classes import`

But when I try to use the ORM, i get the following error:

```
for instance in session.query(Team):
...     print instance.id
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2224, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2239, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1450, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1583, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1697, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1690, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.7-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: teams u'SELECT teams.id AS teams_id, teams.name AS teams_name, teams.flag AS teams_flag, teams.url AS teams_url \nFROM teams' ()
```

Comment: Is it possible that your `session` connects to a different database (file) as the `engine` is bound to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it can't find the table teams- confirm with SqlLite ( I use firefox plugin) that it exists and that is the name. Also, copy the SQL in the error message in a Sqlite window and see if it runs.

Comment: yes, I'm also using firefox plugin, the sql statement "SELECT teams.id AS teams_id, teams.name AS teams_name, teams.flag AS teams_flag, teams.url AS teams_url FROM teams" runs

Comment: Sometimes you need to put the database name before the table, i.e. "mydb.teams"